# Performance DataPortal_Fetch()

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, csla

Is there a way to improve the performance of a Fetch? I'm loading a pretty huge Table with many Fields (not all are used for my View) but it takes to long  ( 8 -10sec for 500 data set). Im not Loading all the data just the one which I need.

Does more parameter in the Fetch improve the speed of the loading?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand the scenario.  Is the calling of DataPortal_Fetch slow, or is the dal responding slowly within your DataPortal_Fetch override?

Answer (score 0):

You can't add more parameters to a DataPortal_Fetch (at least, not without rewriting a pretty significant portion of CSLA); it takes 0 or 1 parameters of type object (you can get around that w/ a criteria class, but that won't help your performance issue).

There are a few factors that play into the speed:

- Indexing on the db (assuming it's a RDBMS)
- Network latency (this is typically the big one)
- Size of the object graph itself; there's not much you can do about that aside from trying to shrink it

If you're not already doing so, be sure you're using a CompressedProxy if going across the wire, see [here](http://www.lhotka.net/cslanet/faq/SilverlightDataPortalCompression.ashx) for details.